# Error: Cannot Implicitly convert type 'int?' to 'string'

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

```
public void selectqueryasso()
{
   CustomerOrderResult cso=new CustomerOrderResult();
   var asso = from as1 in ds.orders
      from as2 in ds.order_details
      where (as1.oid == as2.oid)
      orderby as1.pname
      select new CustomerOrderResult 
      {
         oid = Convert.ToInt32(as1.oid),
         cmny =as1.cmny,
         ocountry=as1.ocountry,
         pname=as1.pname,
         price=as1.price,
         orderno=as1.orderno,
         saltitle=as1.saltitle,
      };
      GridView1.DataSource = asso;
      GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

> Error:Cannot Implicitly convert type 'int?' to 'string' Error:Cannot
>   Implicitly convert type 'int?' to 'string' Error:Cannot Implicitly
>   convert type 'int?' to 'string' Error:Cannot Implicitly convert type
>   'int?' to 'string' Error:Cannot Implicitly convert type 'int?' to
>   'string'

Comment: So would you mind to show us `CustomerOrderResult` and mention the types in `ds.orders`?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the error is from:  oid = Convert.ToInt32(as1.oid),?

Next time please make sure to explain it a little more.

From what I can gather, your int value can be null, therefore you cannot cast it unless you are using the value, otherwise it will give a null pointer exception:

```
oid = Convert.ToInt32(as1.oid.Value),
```

So instead of using as1.oid, use as1.oid.Value.

It would be wise to also check if the value is null or not:

```
if(as1.oid.HasValue)
```